# HTML folder located within IOS Image file?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I have two 3750G switches in a Cisco switchstack

I wasn't sure if this was common at one point or not, but when I go to copy a new IOS image .bin onto flash, It is showing not enough space. Upon further investigation, I find that there is a large folder with an IOS image directory called HTML.

Does anyone know if this HTML folder and files was used for any reason or is even legitimate?

````
Switch Ports Model              SW Version            SW Image
------ ----- -----              ----------            ----------
*    1 28    WS-C3750G-24PS     12.2(53)SE2           C3750-IPBASEK9-M
     2 24    WS-C3750G-24T      12.2(53)SE2           C3750-IPBASEK9-M

3750-2#dir flash2:
Directory of flash2:/

    2  -rwx        6792  Mar 28 2019 03:13:33 +00:00  config.text
    3  drwx         192  Aug 12 2010 18:57:49 +00:00  c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE2
    4  -rwx         676   Mar 1 1993 00:01:41 +00:00  vlan.dat
    5  -rwx        1930  Mar 28 2019 03:13:33 +00:00  private-config.text
  445  -rwx        3096   Mar 1 1993 00:01:53 +00:00  multiple-fs
  446  -rwx        6717   Oct 1 2018 10:16:35 +00:00  config.text.backup
  447  -rwx        1930   Oct 1 2018 10:16:35 +00:00  private-config.text.backup


3750-2#dir
Directory of flash2:/c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE2/

    6  -rwx    11494274  Aug 12 2010 18:56:23 +00:00  c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE2.bin
    7  drwx        4608  Aug 12 2010 18:57:37 +00:00  html
  444  -rwx         681  Aug 12 2010 18:57:51 +00:00  info

15998976 bytes total (1538048 bytes free)


3750-2#dir
Directory of flash2:/c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE2/html/

    8  -rwx       13756  Aug 12 2010 18:56:23 +00:00  forms.js
    9  -rwx         865  Aug 12 2010 18:56:23 +00:00  helpframework.js
   10  -rwx       12467  Aug 12 2010 18:56:23 +00:00  sitewide.js
   11  -rwx       41015  Aug 12 2010 18:56:24 +00:00  fpv.js
   12  -rwx       28348  Aug 12 2010 18:56:24 +00:00  ajax.js
   13  -rwx          62  Aug 12 2010 18:56:24 +00:00  more.txt
   14  -rwx       22059  Aug 12 2010 18:56:25 +00:00  stylesheet.css
   15  -rwx        1749  Aug 12 2010 18:56:25 +00:00  appsui.js
   16  -rwx       39650  Aug 12 2010 18:56:26 +00:00  graph.js
---omitted---

15998976 bytes total (1538048 bytes free)```


The other switch in my switchstack doesnt show it as a directory for an IOS image

```Cisco3750-2#dir flash1:
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx    11494274   Mar 1 1993 00:09:25 +00:00  c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-53.SE2.bin
    3  -rwx        1930  Mar 28 2019 03:13:33 +00:00  private-config.text
    4  -rwx         676   Mar 1 1993 00:01:12 +00:00  vlan.dat
    5  -rwx    12111413  Mar 28 2019 03:12:08 +00:00  c3750-ipbasek9-mz.122-55.SE12.bin
    6  -rwx        3096  Mar 28 2019 03:13:33 +00:00  multiple-fs
    8  -rwx        6792  Mar 28 2019 03:13:33 +00:00  config.text

32514048 bytes total (8892928 bytes free)```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML folder is something that Cisco provides for you to use the HTTP/HTTPS server in the device. Most engineers use the command line, and the HTTP/HTTPS server can be disabled (it presents some security risk).

If you do not use the HTTP/HTTPS server for configuration, you can disable it with:

```
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
```

The folder can then be safely removed.

Answer (score 3):

I'll put that in another answer, although it will miss the question somewhat.

I discourage the use of the "naked" .bin files with 3700 series stacks for the following reasons:

- needs to be copied to all stack members, manually, and checksum-verified on all of them
- bootvar needs to be maintained manually, on all stack members
- upgrades are more time-consuming and error-prone than needed

Instead, use the .tar file and the `archive download-sw ...` commands, with their numerous of options like `/imageonly`, `/leave-old-sw` or `/overwrite`, most of which are pretty self-explanatory. They automate a lot of the steps required and require a lot less interaction.

The command's been around for quite while now:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_55_se/commmand/reference/3750cr/cli1.html#28822

Answer (score 2):

The HTML directory contains the files for the device manager. If you have no need for it, then it can be deleted without issue. (And then install direct bin images instead of the tar package that contains the image and device manager files.)